# How to run this query inside Stored Procedure when session variables are used

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have found this query to [calculate medians](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
@myvar:=0;
@rownum:=0;
SELECT result.readdate, 
       AVG(total_gallons) AS total_gallons 
FROM   (SELECT middle_rows.readdate, 
               numerated_rows.rownum, 
               numerated_rows.total_gallons 
        FROM   (SELECT IF(@myvar = readdate, @rownum := @rownum + 1, @rownum := 0) AS rownum,
                       @myvar := readdate                                          AS readdate_alias,
                       total_gallons 
                FROM   _temp_total_gallons 
                ORDER  BY readdate, 
                          total_gallons) numerated_rows, 
               (SELECT readdate, 
                       COUNT(*) / 2 median 
                FROM   _temp_total_gallons
                GROUP  BY readdate) middle_rows 
        WHERE  numerated_rows.rownum BETWEEN ( middle_rows.median - IF(median = ROUND(median), 1, 0) - 0.5 ) AND ( middle_rows.median - IF(median = ROUND(median), 0, 0.5) )
               AND numerated_rows.readdate_alias = middle_rows.readdate) result
GROUP  BY readdate
```

As you see it uses `@myvar` and `@rownum` as session variables `SELECT IF(@myvar = readdate, @rownum := @rownum + 1, @rownum := 0)`

The problem is that can't run this inside Stored Procedure because `@myvar:=0` syntax is unknown, and I must reference/set inside-select runtime.

How would you rewrite the above query to be used in Stored Procedure?

Sample data to test with and the query can be found at https://gist.github.com/948250
**A second set of data to test with is here https://gist.github.com/25b991396d0dd6968b7e**

Comment: They are called session variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SET @myvar := 0;
```

inside an SP to assign a value:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_median()
BEGIN
SET @myvar:=0;
SET @rownum:=0;
SELECT result.readdate,
       AVG(total_gallons) AS total_gallons
FROM   (SELECT middle_rows.readdate,
               numerated_rows.rownum,
               numerated_rows.total_gallons
        FROM   (SELECT IF(@myvar = readdate, @rownum := @rownum + 1, @rownum := 0) AS rownum,
                       @myvar := readdate                                          AS readdate_alias,
                       total_gallons
                FROM   _temp_total_gallons
                ORDER  BY readdate,
                          total_gallons) numerated_rows,
               (SELECT readdate,
                       COUNT(*) / 2 median
                FROM   _temp_total_gallons
                GROUP  BY readdate) middle_rows
        WHERE  numerated_rows.rownum BETWEEN ( middle_rows.median - IF(median = ROUND(median), 1, 0) - 0.5 ) AND ( middle_rows.median - IF(median = ROUND(median), 0, 0.5) )
               AND numerated_rows.readdate_alias = middle_rows.readdate) result
GROUP  BY readdate;
END;
$$
```

Comment: I've tried that and the results are not the same when this query runs from SP(incorrect) and when I execute manually (correct). It seams it misses some rows, probably that in-select variables are not updated in the same way in SP.

Comment: I've included sample data export and the query in the updated question.

Comment: @Pentium10: both return the same values for me: `'2009-04-21', 10890.000000
'2009-08-25', 26300.000000
'2009-10-20', 3300.000000
'2009-10-22', 5036.500000
'2009-12-01', 7837.000000`

Comment: Then why 2009-04-14 and 15 are missing? I will update in a moment the gist with correct data and incorrect results.

Comment: @Pentium10: I don't know. As I said, both return the same.

Comment: I don't know what happens but it misses some data as like the session variables are not reseted properly, see the updated gist to get the difference.

Comment: @Pentium: could you please refine your data to the minimum required to reproduce the problem? 5000 records are quite hard to debug.

Comment: @Quassnoi I've included in the question a lot smaller set of data, and for that the SP does not return results.

Comment: If I run the query inside SQLYog it works fine. I am wondering if the session is treated in different way inside of SP?

Comment: I get to the end, but the problem was weird. I had to change readdate from DATE to VARCHAR and it started to work again in both environments. I can't explain why was working when executed from SQLyog and why wasn't working in the SP. Do you?

Comment: @Pentium: try initializing `@myvar` with `CAST(NULL AS DATE)` instead. Actually, `SQLyog` most probably did not initialize the variables at all and started a new session each time (which means they were initialized to `NULL`). Initializing to an int means that `readdate` is cast to an `INT` on comparison.